# scraping SVG data by CSS Selector and Id (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm looking to scrape a label from an SVG that only arrives with a mouse hover.
I'm working with this [link](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/congestion-management/r2/redispatching-internal/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=GRAPH&areaType=CTA&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.01.2022%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAY&dateTime.endDateTime=02.01.2023%2000:00%7CUTC%7CDAY&area.values=CTY%7C10Y1001A1001A83F!CTA%7C10YDE-VE-------2&dv-datatable_length=10) for the data contained with the [+] expand button to the right in each of the table rows. When you press [+] expand, an SVG table pops up that shows  elements that contain  elements. When you hover on each of the  elements, a  element appears called "Capacity Impact" with a value for each of the bars. These values are the values I want to scrape.

See a screenshot below.

[image]

So far, my code is successful in opening each of the [+] expand buttons, and identifying the polygons but I can't get to the labels using either XPATH or CSS Selectors. See code below.

```py
driver.get(url)
table_button_xpath = "//table[@class='data-view-table redispatching dataTable']//tr//td[@class = 'button-column']//a[@class='openIcon pre-table-button operation-detail-expand small-button ui-button-light ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only']"

driver.find_element(By.ID, "close-button").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "cookieconsent-button").click()
    
# open up all the "+" buttons
table_buttons = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, table_button_xpath)
        
for i in list(range(1, 10)):
        
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, table_button_xpath).click()
        
# find all the polygons
polygons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'path')
    
label_xpath = "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @id = 'ballons')]//*[name()='g']//*[name()='tspan']"
    
for polygon in polygons :
        
    action.move_to_element(polygon)
        
    labels_by_xpath = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, label_xpath)
    labels_by_css_selector = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg>#ballons>g>text>tspan")
```

Both labels_by_xpath and labels_by_css_selector return a list of 0 elements. I've tried many versions of both the xpath and css selector approach, along with using WebDriverWait, but I can't get it to return the capacity impact values.

HTML screenshot is also copied below (to be clear, the number I need to scrape is the "50" text in the tag.

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thank you,
Sophie

Comment: is the XPath/CSS selector returning anything in the chrome console, or it is returning zero results?

Comment: in stead off the `name()` function try the `local-name()` function

Comment: @RohitPratap it's returning zero results but it's tricky because the cursor has to be hovering over the SVG polygons so it's actually quite hard to get the inspect to show the #ballons element even manually

Comment: okay if you say the div appears on hover why are you clicking instead of hovering on the element

Comment: @Sophie and can you correct the syntax of your code also it's confusing you are clicking on the same element 10 times

Comment: Hi @RohitPratap you're referring to the section of the code where I am pressing the "+" expand button in order to reveal the SVG charts. I'm using the class of buttons that is only assigned to unexpanded buttons. There are ten rows (and therefore 10 charts) per page and so we have to click the expand button ten times. 

Only after this section of code do I start searching for the data values inside of the expanded SVG charts where I do not use any click functions, because as you say, it's unclickable. This is the section I was asking for advice on

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed i tried it just in case (didn't change the error) but I understood that they're actually syntactically the same?

Comment: what I understood is the problem you are facing is not with the identifier but you are trying to find an element before it is available in the DOM. you might be missing some steps that will lead the element to be registered in DOM (like hovering on the bar ). or if it's having any iframe you might need to switch to that too. i don't have the idea of the application so just assuming things here

Comment: one debugging suggestion take a screenshot after hovering and see if it's actually hovering in case of headless mode or just running in headed mode. to see where the script is failing.

Comment: @RohitPratap Agreed! Although I have debugged this step - even if I run it in headed mode and place the cursor over the polygon before I run the last two lines, the call returns a zero list.

Comment: to replicate the hover functionality manually you can use ':hov' in the style tab of the chrome console and see on hovering which element will be making the div visible. I am guessing it will be an iframe and you will be needing to switch to that iframe before you can interact with the element. but what I can do is the guessing about possible solutions, is it possible to get my hands on the web application?

Comment: @RohitPratap perhaps it is helpful to say that running

 x = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg>g>g>text>tspan")

where #ballons is replaced by 'g' here, does work and does return 50. it just returns it among all other text in the SVG.

Comment: @RohitPratap yes the link is listed in the question (i've copied it again here): https://transparency.entsoe.eu/congestion-management/r2/redispatching-internal/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=GRAPH&areaType=CTA&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.01.2022+00:00|UTC|DAY&dateTime.endDateTime=02.01.2023+00:00|UTC|DAY&area.values=CTY|10Y1001A1001A83F!CTA|10YDE-VE-------2&dv-datatable_length=10

Comment: @RohitPratap omg. I was spelling balloons wrong. this works: 

x = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg>[id^='balloons']>g>text>tspan")

Comment: @Sophie Hey, cool man I also wrote the selector and it worked I was confused why it's not working for you. I saw your comment now you found it on your own too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is with the locator.
Here is the updated locator to select the desired element.

CSS Selector :

```
svg>[id^='balloons']>g:nth-child(2)>text:nth-child(2)>tspan
```

try this to get the element Capacity 50

Answer (score 0):

x = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg>[id^='balloons']>g>text>tspan")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).